# Apache try full filename (GET parameters as part of filename)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver

I have files on my Apache webserver with names like "`index.cfm?PageID=30`" where `?PageID=30` is a part of the actual filename. How can I set up `.htaccess` to make Apache open these files correctly without using `PageID` as URL parameters?

I use `try_files $uri $uri$args` for similar issues in Nginx, but I'm new with Apache.

Same for files like "`news.asp?sec=news&article=24`".

I just need to 200 OK (with content of file `/var/example/news.asp?sec=news&article=24`) when I ask for page `example.com/news.asp?sec=news&article=24`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the correct code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1\%3F%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NE]

</IfModule>
```

You can check how it works mt website. For example `http://www.drugeducationforum.com/index.cfm?PageID=30`
Where `index.cfm?PageID=30` is a full name of the file.